# Why is my performance bad? (Noob scheduling)

Tags: halide

I'm mainly a very high level programmer so thinking about things like CPU locality is very new to me.

I'm working on a basic bilinear demosaic (for RGGB sensor data) and I've got the algorithm right (judging by the results) but it's not performing as well as I'd hoped (~210Mpix/s).

Here's my code (the input is a 4640x3472 image with a single channel of RGGB):

```
def get_bilinear_debayer(input_raw, print_nest=False):
    x, y, c = Var(), Var(), Var()

    # Clamp and move to 32 bit for lots of space for averaging.
    input = Func()
    input[x,y] = cast(
        UInt(32),
        input_raw[
            clamp(x,0,input_raw.width()-1),
            clamp(y,0,input_raw.height()-1)]
    )

    # Interpolate vertically
    vertical = Func()
    vertical[x,y] = (input[x,y-1] + input[x,y+1])/2

    # Interpolate horizontally
    horizontal = Func()
    horizontal[x,y] = (input[x-1,y] + input[x+1,y])/2

    # Interpolate on diagonals
    diagonal_average = Func()
    diagonal_average[x, y] = (
        input[x+1,y-1] + 
        input[x+1,y+1] +
        input[x-1,y-1] +
        input[x-1,y+1])/4

    # Interpolate on adjacents
    adjacent_average = Func()
    adjacent_average[x, y] = (horizontal[x,y] + vertical[x,y])/2

    red, green, blue = Func(), Func(), Func()

    # Calculate the red channel
    red[x, y, c] = select(
        # Red photosite
        c == 0, input[x, y],
        # Green photosite
        c == 1, select(x%2 == 0, vertical[x,y],
                                 horizontal[x,y]),
        # Blue photosite
        diagonal_average[x,y]
    )

    # Calculate the blue channel
    blue[x, y, c] = select(
        # Blue photosite
        c == 2, input[x, y],
        # Green photosite
        c == 1, select(x%2 == 1, vertical[x,y],
                                 horizontal[x,y]),
        # Red photosite
        diagonal_average[x,y]
    )

    # Calculate the green channel
    green[x, y, c] = select(
        # Green photosite
        c == 1, input[x,y],
        # Red/Blue photosite
        adjacent_average[x,y]
    )

    # Switch color interpolator based on requested color.
    # Specify photosite as third argument, calculated as [x, y, z] = (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2)
    # Happily works out to a sum of x mod 2 and y mod 2.
    debayer = Func()
    debayer[x, y, c] = select(c == 0, red[x, y, x%2 + y%2],
                              c == 1, green[x, y, x%2 + y%2],
                                      blue[x, y, x%2 + y%2])


    # Scheduling
    x_outer, y_outer, x_inner, y_inner, tile_index = Var(), Var(), Var(), Var(), Var()

    bits = input_raw.get().type().bits

    output = Func()
    # Cast back to the original colour space
    output[x,y,c] = cast(UInt(bits), debayer[x,y,c])
    # Reorder so that colours are calculated in order (red runs, then green, then blue)

    output.reorder_storage(c, x, y)
    # Tile in 128x128 squares
    output.tile(x, y, x_outer, y_outer, x_inner, y_inner, 128, 128)
    # Vectorize based on colour
    output.bound(c, 0, 3)
    output.vectorize(c)
    # Fuse and parallelize
    output.fuse(x_outer, y_outer, tile_index)
    output.parallel(tile_index)

    # Debugging
    if print_nest:
        output.print_loop_nest()
        debayer.print_loop_nest()
        red.print_loop_nest()
        green.print_loop_nest()
        blue.print_loop_nest()

    return output
```

Honestly I have no idea what I'm doing here and I'm too new to this to have any clue where or what to look at.

*Any* advice on how to improve the scheduling is helpful. I'm still learning but feedback is hard to find.

The schedule I have is the best I've been able to do but it's pretty much entirely trial and error.

EDIT: I added an extra 30Mpix/s by doing the whole adjacent average summation in the function directly and by vectorizing on x_inner instead of colour.

EDIT: New schedule:

```
# Set input bounds.
output.bound(x, 0, (input_raw.width()/2)*2)
output.bound(y, 0, (input_raw.height()/2)*2)
output.bound(c, 0, 3)

# Reorder so that colours are calculated in order (red runs, then green, then blue)
output.reorder_storage(c, x, y)
output.reorder(c, x, y)

# Tile in 128x128 squares
output.tile(x, y, x_outer, y_outer, x_inner, y_inner, 128, 128)
output.unroll(x_inner, 2).unroll(y_inner,2)

# Vectorize based on colour
output.unroll(c)
output.vectorize(c)

# Fuse and parallelize
output.fuse(x_outer, y_outer, tile_index)
output.parallel(tile_index)
```

EDIT: Final schedule that's now beating (640MP/s) the [Intel Performance Primitive benchmark](http://www.fastcompression.com/products/debayer/benchmarks.htm) that was run on a CPU [twice as powerful as mine](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=1907&cmp[]=2502):

```
output = Func()

# Cast back to the original colour space
output[x,y,c] = cast(UInt(bits), debayer[x,y,c])

# Set input bounds.
output.bound(x, 0, (input_raw.width()/2)*2)
output.bound(y, 0, (input_raw.height()/2)*2)
output.bound(c, 0, 3)

# Tile in 128x128 squares
output.tile(x, y, x_outer, y_outer, x_inner, y_inner, 128, 128)
output.unroll(x_inner, 2).unroll(y_inner, 2)

# Vectorize based on colour
output.vectorize(x_inner, 16)

# Fuse and parallelize
output.fuse(x_outer, y_outer, tile_index)
output.parallel(tile_index)

target = Target()
target.arch = X86
target.os = OSX
target.bits = 64
target.set_feature(AVX)
target.set_feature(AVX2)
target.set_feature(SSE41)

output.compile_jit(target)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you are using unroll(c) to make the per-channel select logic optimize away. Unrolling by 2 in x and y will also help:

```
output.unroll(x, 2).unroll(y,2)
```

The goal there is to optimize out the select logic between even/odd rows and columns. In order to take full advantage of that, you'll likely also need to tell Halide that the min and extent are a multiple of 2:

```
output.output_buffer().set_bounds(0,
                                  (f.output_buffer().min(0) / 2) * 2,
                                  (output.output_buffer().extent(0) / 2) * 2)
output.output_buffer().set_bounds(1,
                                  (f.output_buffer().min(1) / 2) * 2,
                                  (output.output_buffer().extent(1) / 2) * 2)
```

Though it may be worth stating even more stringent constraints, such as using 128 instead of 2 to assert multiples of the tile size or just hardwiring the min and extent to reflect the actual sensor parameters if you are only supporting a single camera.

Comment: I updated my post with the new schedule adjusted with your comments. This way it gets up to 360MPix/s which is pretty good. I know that Intel has  a debayer algorithm that gets up to 630 though: http://www.fastcompression.com/products/debayer/benchmarks.htm

Comment: Vectorizing on c is limited as there are only three elements. Sometimes you can unroll by a larger factor to get consistent lane mapping and process multiple vectors of color channel information at once. (E.g. Unrolling by 4 gives 3 32x4 vectors at once. It will probably work here as raw processing usually has a large enough minimum alignment constraint -- images are a multiple of 16 or 32 etc.)

However a better bet would be to vectorize on x, which allows larger vectorization widths. At that point there is a factor of 2 to be had by making the computation fit into 16-bit integers.

Comment: Okay, so I crammed things into 16-bit integers and vectorized on x_inner and that got it up to about 480MP/s. The biggest win though was manually specifying the build target. When I manually asked for 64-bit OSX with AVX, AVX2 and SSE4.1, I got 640MP/s out of it, which is beating the Intel Performance Primitive benchmark from earlier, despite running on a CPU that's half as powerful as the one that benchmark was run on.